# On CentOS when I statically assign on ip address to my second interface , my primary nat interface does not work

Tags: centos, networking, nat

When I statically assign an IP address to my second interface , my primary NAT interface does not work. I am new to Cent OS and I am using NAT and when I change the second interface statically , my first network interface disappears.

Comment: It's hard to answer given the information provided.  Could you provide more details, like the command used to assign the IP to the second interface, what you mean by "does not work"?  Maybe even the output from commands like "ip address show" and "iptables --list --verbose --numeric --table nat" (assuming there is not sensitive information in those outputs for your particular setup).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste the `ens33` network script to `ens37`, because it brings the same UUID attribute. Make sure to comment/delete the UUID or it won't work.